# Magento 2 : Reorder Throw Exception

Tags: magento2.4, sales-order, reorder

After successful purchase in the order details page when i click reorder option it throw below exception

> TypeError: Magento\Framework\DataObject::__construct(): Argument #1
> ($data) must be of type array, null given, called in
> /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Reorder/OrderInfoBuyRequestGetter.php
> on line 65 and defined in
> /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/DataObject.php:40

Comment: If you are using third party extension related to order, try to disable that and then check.

Comment: I add a product to the cart programmatically using events. If I do not add a product programmatically, that means the reorder action will not throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my scenario, I add a product to the cart programmatically. In the code, I did not add the necessary data for ordering products. So in the Database the sale_order_item table product_option column has an empty array of data. When I add the data in the quote item for ordering products, then the data correctly saved in the sale_order_item table product_option column, it won't throw an exception for me!.

```
    $url = 'Your url';
    $uenc = base64_encode($url);
    $productOptions = [
          'info_buyRequest' => [
              'uenc' => $uenc,
              'product' => $productId,
              'qty' => 1
          ]
    ];
    $quoteItem->addOption([
         'product_id' => $productId,
         'code' => 'info_buyRequest',
         'value' => json_encode($productOptions)
    ]);
    $quote->save();
```